# How to properly position inclined text of different sizes into a specific zone?

Tags: css

I am trying to position a piece of text (fixed font and max length of 6) on top of an image. The image will be of a product and I have to show how customer's text would look onto that product.

**The tricks are** :

- the text is inclined
- needs to be responsive (mobile screens are most important for now)

This is what I have so far [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/belun/enjuhp87/1/), but I reckon some math has to be done on the positioning of the sample text (using the css *calc()* function)

### Borders

*(these will not stay and are there for better understanding positions)*

- black borders show the image's border and where the text needs to fit
- red border is the container of the image and the overlayed text
- green border it the container of the overlayed text

```css
#sample-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}

#sample-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

#sample-text {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 35%;
  right: 59%;
  text-align: right;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 5vw;
  transform: rotate(-16deg);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Verdana";
}
```

```html
<div id="sample-container">
  <img id="sample-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/R9qKGMb/sample-image.png">
  <div id="sample-text">SAMPLE</div>
</div>
```

**The problems:**

- text of different lengths messes up my positioning
- (extra : if this is shown on a desktop website, where the content is centered on the page and there are margins on left and right, for better readability I suppose, then using measurements relative to the viewport breaks the positioning on resizing; the sample code does not show this problem yet, as it allows the image to be full page width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to make the text container to have a width equal to 0 and rely on overflow. Doing so you will always position the same element (width/height) whataver the text inside:

```css
#sample-text-configuration-container {
  position: relative;
}

#sample-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:red;
}

#sample-image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sample-text {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top:39%;
    right:80%;
    text-align:right;
    color: gray;
    font-size:5vw;
    transform: rotate(-16deg);
    width:0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Verdana";
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div id="sample-text-configuration-container">
  <span>Custom text:</span>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    maxlength=6 
    value="SAMPLE" 
    onfocus="this.value=''"             
    oninput="document.getElementById('sample-text').innerHTML = this.value;"/>

  <br/>
  <span>Text top position:</span>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    value="39%"
    oninput="document.getElementById('sample-text').style.top = this.value;"/>

  <br/>
  <span>Text right position:</span>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    value="80%"
    onkeydown="document.getElementById('sample-text').style.left = this.value;"/>
  
  <br/>
  <span>Text size:</span>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    value="5vw" 
    oninput="document.getElementById('sample-text').style.fontSize = this.value;"/>

<div id="sample-container">
  <img id="sample-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/R9qKGMb/sample-image.png">
  <div id="sample-text">SAMPLE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: one small issue with this solution is that the text is aligned left (well, fake aligned left, as it overflows towards the right of the text container) and the desired state is different (left align). anyway, your suggestion gave me the idea of just making the text container fixed width, this way i have control of the text alignment also. thx.
sample code : https://jsfiddle.net/belun/vs0x32qj/6/